# Use different resources for different application flavors using gradle

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-resources

I have an android application and I would like to have different flavors. Specifically I would like to have 2 flavors and for each flavor use different strings (different `strings.xml` file) and maybe have some icons different.

I have tried creating two folders in the project's root folder: `flav1` and `flav2` and used the following `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:15"
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

    productFlavors {
        flav1 {
            packageName "com.ic.flav1"
        }

        flav2 {
            packageName "com.ic.flav2"
        }
    }

    android.sourceSets.flav2 {
        res {
            srcDir 'flav2'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'flav2'
        }
    }
    android.sourceSets.flav1 {
        res {
            srcDir 'flav1'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'flav1'
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is that none of the strings is recognized, getting multiple errors of the following type:

> build FAILED :
>
> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'contentDescription' with value '@string/txt_addr').

Am I missing something? How should the build.gradle be?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was to add directory

> values

under each corresponding res folder, and all the strings were recognized.

Comment: what is the difference between "res" and "resources" ?  i'm an AS newbie coming from eclipse... i see the folder in my project but i'm not sure what it does and how you would benefit from having a separate "resources" for each flavor?

Comment: Res and resources is the same thing. It's just the naming convention that AS uses ("res"). 
Having different resources for each flavor would give you the opportunity for example to have different images for the same resource id (e.g. R.id.logo can be a different image in different flavors)